# Lua rewrite function

Tags: function, lua

Hey is it possible to rewrite a function (add code inside it)
I really want to execute my code in the function that the user is executing.
Without an other argument

Like this:

```
function exampel(fnct)
     fnct( function()  
        print('code thad i want to add') 
     end)
end

exampel( function() -- function user is executing
    print('ok')
end)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run code before and after the function runs:

```
function wrap(f,b,a)
    return function (...) b(...) f(...) a(...) end
end

function before()
    print"before"
end

function after()
    print"after"
end

function user()
    print"user code"
end

wrap(user,before,after)()
```

Comment: Is there a way to put code inside a existing function ?

Comment: @Péèlo In the function you posted, the only places you could run your own code inside it are equivalent to running it at the beginning or end. Please edit your question to include a better example if you want to do something else.

Comment: The thing is it is for detecting a cheat and the function of user is not executed in the same file I want to modify the function he is executing  and it loads in his file and not where i created the function

Answer (score 0):

here is a global function `load`(lua5.4),you can use it to dynamic execute a lua code.

```lua
local str = [[
    local a = 3
    local b = 4
    return a+b
]]

print(load(str)())--7
```

Comment: But is it possibel to inserd code in a function like this ? function: 000001D488E47EA0